# Adding two JSON object and creating new one

Tags: jquery, json

I have two JSON objects

```
 Arr1 ={Email: "abc@domain.com", status: "0"}
 Arr2 ={Email: "xyz@domain.com", status: "1"}
```

When I try to make third array like,

```
Arr3 = Arr1.push( Arr2  )
```

It doesn't append correctly but second array is added as a list than a object. What am I missing ?
I am expecting push will create results like,

```
{Email: "abc@domain.com", status: "0"},
{Email: "xyz@domain.com", status: "1"}
```

Comment: It's an *object* !

Comment: Both are objects but push making it a list than a object.

Comment: You can use `$.extend`

Comment: so, you want like a new object have the above two objects as nested one?

Comment: Yes, append second to the first object

Comment: have you tried doing `Arr3 = { Arr1, Arr2 }` ?

Comment: You cant merge like this @Palash

Comment: Oh you want to merge, then just try `Arr3 = {...Arr1, ...Arr2}`

Comment: @Pedram, tried extend too. See the updated post

Comment: You can try `Arr1.concat(Arr2)`.

Comment: @TDuong that will give an error as both Arr1 & Arr2 actually _object_ here.

Comment: From the image, I saw that `Arr1` and `Arr2` are arrays of object! @palaѕн

Comment: @TDuong Ok, I see that now but OP has mentioned in his comment that "_Both are objects_" so I am confused again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting push will create results like,

```
{Email: "abc@domain.com", status: "0"},
{Email: "xyz@domain.com", status: "1"}
```

This result is not valid to me, you should use another `object` or `array` except you make it to `string`

```js
let Arr1 = {
  Email: "abc@domain.com",
  status: "0"
};
let Arr2 = {
  Email: "xyz@domain.com",
  status: "1"
};

let str1 = JSON.stringify(Arr1);
let str2 = JSON.stringify(Arr2);
console.log(str2, ',' + str2)
```

*This makes no sense!*

---

You have two way, add `objects` into one `array`, or add two `object` into one `object`

## 1.

```js
let Arr1 = {
  Email: "abc@domain.com",
  status: "0"
};
let Arr2 = {
  Email: "xyz@domain.com",
  status: "1"
};

var Arr3 = {Arr1, Arr2}
console.log(Arr3)
```

## 2.

```js
let Arr1 = {
  Email: "abc@domain.com",
  status: "0"
};
let Arr2 = {
  Email: "xyz@domain.com",
  status: "1"
};

let Arr3 = [];

Arr3.push(Arr1, Arr2)
console.log(Arr3)
```